# Making arithmetic progression intuitive, the problem of pairs

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

$$a_n=a_0+2n$$
$$S_p=a_0+a_1+...+a_{p-1}$$
In $S_p$ is $a_0+a_{p-1}=a_n+a_{(p-1)-n}=C$. Thus every pair $a_n, a_{(p-1)-n}$ can be expressed as a constant value $C$. In $S_p$ there exist $\frac{1}{2}p$ pairs $a_n, a_{(p-1)-n}$.

Hence $S_p=\frac{1}{2}pC, p\ge2$ and $S_p=a_0, p=1$ and $S_p=undefined, p=0$.

However I find it not intuitive that for $p=3$ there exist $1,5$ pairs. I tried to express the problem geometrically instead of using the word "pair." Which rule of mathematics can I use to say that despite my lack of intuition according to mathematics the above is correct?

Comment: If the number of summands is odd, just pair all elements with the exception of the middle element. Note that the middle element is $\frac{a_0+a_{p-1}}{2}$. So, you could consider the middle element to be a "half-pair".

Comment: An "empty" sum is usually considered to have value $0$.

Comment: @Peter Can you calculate $S_0$ using the equation of $S_p$? I haven't defined $S_p$ to be $S_p=0+a_0+a_1+...+a_{n-1}$,

Comment: The convention with the empty sum is not important. If it confuses you, forget it.

Comment: @Peter the middle element is $a_{p-1/2}$ how do you conclude that $a_{p-1/2}=\frac{a_0+a_{p-1}}{2}$?

Comment: The middle element has equal distances to $a_0$ and $a_{p-1}$, so it must be the arithmetic mean of them.

Comment: @Peter notice that $C=a_{\frac{p-1}{2}}+a_{(p-1)-\frac{p-1}{2}}=a_1+a_{1}=a_0+a_2$ for $p=3$. So you define a pair consisting of two unique elements and you say that for every uneven numbers of terms there exist a "0,5-pair" cause it pairs with itself?

Comment: Yes, but instead of "uneven", you should use the word "odd." The pairing begins with the first and the last summand and ends with a number "pairing with itself", if the number of summands is odd. The only exception is the case $1$ summand, but this case is trivial and rather boring :)

Comment: @Peter Why would you say that the case with 1 is exceptional. It follows the same rule I've described for odd numbers.

Comment: In some sense, yes. The first and last summand are equal to the middle summand in this case.